# Sencha Touch 2 Navigationview pop and push event listener

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a navigationView with some items on it, if I `pop` the item, and `push` a modified one back, the event listeners in my controller no longer trigger. How can I get them to work again? I don't get it because each item destroyed and created from scratch when I push it back. Autodestroy is enabled.

```
//Add a view
this.view = Ext.create('ec.view.view1')
this.getNavigation().push(this.view);

//Remove a view (or press back in the navigationview)
this.getNavigation().pop();

//Add a fresh view back
this.view = Ext.create('ec.view.view1')
this.getNavigation().push(this.view);
```

Controller tap handler

```
refs {
    button : '#button'
},
control : {
    button : {
        tap: 'OnTap'
    }
},
OnTap: function() { console.log("Tap") }
```

With the above, all the events, taps, etc break for the view

Comment: I updated it with some code.

Comment: Updated with my listeners, its fairly standard code which causes the issue

Comment: mail me the project or share it on senchafiddle

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, search for loads of forums, lost lots of time, got angry about Sencha support and finally moved the button handler code from the controller back into the view:

```
 xtype: 'button',
 text: 'Save',
 handler: function(button, event) {
     console.log('button pressed');
 }
```

"Dirty", but it works.

I suspect the cause of this behavior is NavigationView.pop() destroying the actual NavigationView, but not it's subordinate objects.